# How do I navigate to a page from top level app page using react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've created a global listener at the top level of my react native app.  I would like to use NavigationActions to navigate to 'SomePage' in the app whenever a bluetooth device disconnects from the app.

The problem is that I have all my navigation set up in a different part of the app(RootPage). So I don't have access to this.props.navigation which is what I usually use to navigate to different pages in the app.  I do *NOT* want to change the navigation object that is created in RootPage.

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        StatusBarManager.initialStatusBarSetup();
        OVTracker.initialize();
        // Save with AsyncStorage
        persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage });
        this.setupBluetooth();
    }
    setupBluetooth() {
        global.oliveDeviceStatusChanged = aBluetoothEventEmitter.addListener('aDeviceStatusChanged', event => {
            if (EventUtils.eventCodeEquals(event, 'DISCONNECTED')) {
                console.log('show me navigationaction', NavigationActions)
                // NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SomePage' })


            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RootPage />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SomeApp', () => App);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this if you want to try navigation on the top page.

```js
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
~~~js
const YourAppContainer = createAppContainer(TopLevelNavigator);
...
      <YourAppContainer
        ref={navigatorRef => {this.navigation = navigatorRef}}
      />
....
  this.navigation.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: No, by top level, I mean that it's the first thing that gets loaded.  The page I want to access is NOT the first page that gets loaded.  Also, I do not have access to this.props.navigation because the navigator stack is created in RootPage, which is one level below App.

Comment: @VK1 I modified the answer after looking at your comments.

Comment: would I put <Provider store={store}>
                <RootPage />
            </Provider> inside <YourAppContainer />?

Comment: Isn't RootPage your container?

Comment: Provider is the main wrapper..so I guess yeah RootPage would be my container.

Comment: Then you can declare a reference in your container as my answer.